# echo=False by default in pweave

Tags: python, markdown, pweave

How can I set the flag echo=False by default to all code, when precessing a python-script file with pweave.

Minimal example:

```
#' # Minimal example.

#' This is a minimal example, which
#' says 'hello' to you.

#+ echo=False
print('Hello')

#' The end.
```

Which gets processed by

```
# either: py to html
pypublish test.py

# or: py to markdown
pweave -f pandoc test.py
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include the following lines at the very beginning of your document:
1.set the echo false for the first code chunk and then change it to false for every other code chunk.
2.You can have a look in the documentation http://mpastell.com/pweave/defaults.html

```
#+ echo = False
import pweave
pweave.rcParams["chunk"]["defaultoptions"].update({'echo' : False,
'f_pos' : "h!"})
```

Following the documentation you can also change other parameters, I have picked 'f_pos' from documentation.